# Prerender unable to access relative url assets

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework2, seo, prerender

I am using zf2 and angular js for my frontend. ZF2 controller makes an api call and returns the data to view(phtml file). In phtml file I am using php to generate meta tags and rest of the content of the page is generated by angular js. Do I still need to serve prerendered pages to google bots since meta tags are already generated by php and I think google bots needs meta tags?To test prerender.io i installed it on my server to generate static page but it is unable to load css, js and images because I am using css, js and images as relative urls in my html page.

Comment: Relative URLs will work fine once the HTML is proxied through your server with the Prerender middleware. You're likely just seeing that because you are accessing the Prerender server directly in your browser.

Comment: @prerender-io I have setup apache middleware by changing htaccess file. Now when I open mydoamin.com/?_escaped_fragment_=  in my browser prerender logs showing that it is trying to access mydomain.com/index.phtml. Since I am using zf2 anf it does not have index.html route so it is showing me zend 404 error page.

Comment: I just responded to your email.